# how to transfer elements from UnorderedList to array using iterable

Tags: java

```
public class Slope<E> implements Comparable {
    
    private Trail[] trail;
    private int ranking;
    private int count;
    
    public Slope (ArrayUnorderedList<Trail> path) {
        trail = new Trail[10];
        
        Iterator<Trail> iter = path.iterator();
        for (int i = 0; i < trail.length; i++) {
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                trail[i] = iter.next();
                count ++;
            }
            
        }
        
    }
```

I want to transfer each of the UnorderedList elements to the
trail array one-by-one using the iterator but it only updates the first value in the array and the rest still point to null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your loop structure; you iterate over `iter` for every single value of `i`.  This will cause you only ever to set the value of `trail[0]` because once you have iterated over `iter` for `i=0`, it's done; `iter.hasNext()` will be `false` for all other values of `i`.

To fix this, you will need to iterate over `iter` without an enclosing for-loop while still keeping track of a running index, which might look something like this:

```java
public class Slope<E> implements Comparable {
    
    private Trail[] trail;
    private int ranking;
    private int count;
    
    public Slope (ArrayUnorderedList<Trail> path) {
        trail = new Trail[10];
 
        Iterator<Trail> iter = path.iterator();
        int i = 0;
        while (iter.hasNext() && i < trail.length) {
            trail[i++] = iter.next();
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```